# Can't Show Google Map in Laravel 5

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, laravel-5

Try to show Google Map through blade.php file using javascript , when i route show blank page in browser . here is Controller code

```
 class ItemsController extends Controller {
   public function map(){
      $items = Item::all();
      return view('items.map',compact('items'));
}
```

}

And blade.php Code

```
@extends('app')
@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div id="map-canvas"></div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        var mapOptions ={
            zoom :4,
            center:new google.maps.LatLng({{$items[0]->location}})
        }
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),mapOptions);;

        @foreach($items as $item)
            var marker{{$item->id}}=new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng({{$item->location}}),
            map:map,
            title:"{{$item->title}}"
        });
        @endforeach

    </script>
```

Database Migration file is here :

```
public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('items', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');

            $table->string('title');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
        DB::statement('ALTER TABLE items ADD location POINT');
    }
```

Comment: what error you have?

Comment: Show Blank page in browser nothing to show any error.

Comment: If you're getting a completely blank page, then it's probably a PHP error. Check the server error log for the error message. If the HTML is there in your browser but the map is not rendering, then check the browser console for error messages.

Comment: Show 2 errors like : 
Uncaught ReferenceError : google is not defined
Uncaught TypeError : window.initMap is not a function @Kryten

Comment: Sounds like you haven't included the google scripts in your HTML. Check out [the tutorial](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial).

Comment: Also you should wrap all your javascript that's creating the map and markers inside a function, and then call that function on window load.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

[https://github.com/fwartner/maps]

Save a lot of time.